# playing 40.000 unit army for game

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

**SOLVED!! (look at my last edit)**

I want to make an army fight of 20.000 vs 20.000 units on canvas. So, for every unit data is:

```
{ 
'id' => 17854,
'x' => 1488, 
'y' => 1269, 
'team' => 'red', 
'health' => 10,
'target' => [1486, 1271]
}
```

And i would to see this fight in real time (25 frames per second).
If i generate 1 frame with Json and save on file, it is 2.5mb size (40k such units with this data).

1 second(25 frames) = 62.5 mb file size. And the fight could last about 30 minutes, so it should use 112gb. This is bad. If i would make the file as binary data, it should take 27 times less place, or 4gb for 30 mins. That's still bad. 2 hrs movie takes 700mb.
I need to save many fights on server. Real players should make their armies and fight each other, so i need the fights to be saved. Every fight is unique, because every damage of every unit is random 0~10 and after unit kills an enemy, it regenerates 1 health. I'm doing calculations with PHP and saving files on server. All 40.000 units are on one screen, all can be visible at once, i want it like that. For now, units are single 2x2 pixel cubes, red and blue teams, its easy to load for javascript. 
But, to generate file with PHP i need about 1 hour. That's another problem. Because for every frame i need to iterate these 40.000 units (for updating x/y, searching for nearby enemies or friends, then for doing damage and returning target or killed enemy coordinates), then iterate over again to unset killed units, and before putting all that into file, i need to iterate over everything and remove unused data that was used for calculations. And to finish this 30 mins fight i need to repeat it 45000 times. Also, every minute there are less and less units. But my point is somehow to make all that file generating in less than a minute, just need a logical way, if some exist.
Questions: 
1) What is the best way to save my files on server and make the files much less on size?
(so far is to use binary data and compress to zip)
2) what is the fastest way to calculate my fights?
(so far is to compile with C++)

// Edited. Here is my whole game code, just like that :)

This is main action:

```
class Simulator
{
    private $units;
    private $places = [];
    private $oldPlaces = [];

    public function initiateGame() {
        $this->createUnits();
        $this->startMoving();
    }

    private function createUnits() {
        foreach(range(0, 150) as $column) { // i like exact army formation to look nice, so its 150x140=21000 units
            foreach (range(0, 140) as $row) {
                $this->setUnits($column, $row);
            }
        }
        $this->oldPlaces = $this->places;
    }

    private function setUnits($column, $row) {
        $beginning_of_team_A = 6; //starting point on canvas for A unit to look nice on screen
        $unit_size_and_free_place = 6; //unit size= 3x3 (look js), and free place between each unit is 3 pixels.
        $beginning_of_team_B = 1100; // next side where enemy army starts appearing
        $x_a = $beginning_of_team_A + $column * $unit_size_and_free_place; // team A
        $y = $beginning_of_team_A + $row * $unit_size_and_free_place; // same for both teams
        $unitA = new Unit($x_a, $y, 1); // 1 is team A (it goes always +1 pixel every frame)
        $this->units[] = $unitA;
        $x_b = $beginning_of_team_B + $column * $unit_size_and_free_place;  // team B
        $unitB = new Unit($x_b, $y, -1); // -1 is team B (it goes always -1 pixel every frame)
        $this->units[] = $unitB;
        $this->places[$x_a.','.$y] = 1; // now that way tracking units, and calculating their next move
        $this->places[$x_b.','.$y] = -2;
    }

    private function startMoving() {
        set_time_limit(30000); // by default after 1 minute it throws exception
        foreach(range(0, 400) as $frame) { //giving 400 frames is like 400/40=10 seconds of action
            $this->places = [];
            foreach($this->units as $unit) {
                $returned = $unit->move($this->oldPlaces); //giving whole units list to every unit to look forward
                $this->places[$returned[0]] = $returned[1]; // returns (next x/y position as string ['1514,148'] ) = ( id as int [15] )
            }
            file_put_contents('assets/games/'.$frame.'.json', json_encode($this->units)); // writing into file  every frame and it uses ~2mb
            $this->oldPlaces = $this->places; //resetting old positions
        }
    }

}
```

This is unit:

```
class Unit
{
    public $x = 0;
    public $y = 0;
    public $team = 1;
    public $stopped;

    public function __construct($x, $y, $team, $stopped = false) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->team = $team;
        $this->stopped = $stopped;
    }

    public function move($places) {
        $this->checkForward($places);
        return [$this->x.','.$this->y, $this->team];
    }

    private function checkForward($places) {
        $forward = $this->x + $this->team; // TODO: find out formula to replace the 4 ifs
        $forward1 = $this->x + $this->team*2;
        $forward2 = $this->x + $this->team*3;
        $forward3 = $this->x + $this->team*4;
        if(isset($places[$forward.','.$this->y])) {
            $this->stopped = true;
        } else if (isset($places[$forward1.','.$this->y])) {
            $this->stopped = true;
        } else if (isset($places[$forward2.','.$this->y])) {
            $this->stopped = true;
        } else if (isset($places[$forward3.','.$this->y])) {
            $this->stopped = true;
        } else {
            $this->stopped = false;
        }

        if($this->stopped == false) { // move forward it is not stopped
            $this->x = $this->x + $this->team;
        }
    }
}
```

This is js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('game', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    var canvas  = document.getElementById("game"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var frame = -2;
    $scope.attacking = false;
    var units = [];

    function start_animation_loop() {
        $scope.promise = $interval(function() {
            if($scope.attacking == true) {
                frame ++;
                if(frame >= 0) {
                    downloadFile();
                    animate();
                }
            }
        }, 40 );
    }

    function downloadFile() {
        $http.get('assets/games/'+frame+'.json').success(function(response) {
            units = response;
        });
    }

    function animate() {
        clear_canvas();
        draw();
    }

    function clear_canvas() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1800, 912);
    }

    function draw() {
        for(var a=0; a<units.length; a++) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillRect(units[a]['x'], units[a]['y'], 3, 3);
            if(units[a]['team'] == 1) {
                context.fillStyle = 'red';
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = 'blue';
            }
        }
    }
    start_animation_loop();

});
```

**SOLVED!** Thx to my colleague in my work! He gave me brilliant idea!

To get the result i needed i just need for every next battle to generate random number (0~10000) and place it into single MySQL database. In addition also put there formations, units, their starting strength, health and everything else. 
And all the calculations do with javascript:
With one constant number (given from backend) i make a formula to always reproduce same army fight -> every unit will move forwards and they always stop at the same time anyways no matter what the calculation. The uniqueness is the random damage every unit gives and what process after. And all the damage will be just their "x/y position somehow compared to constant number" and do whatever to get single damage, random for every unit because they all are in different map positions, but damage will always be 0~10. With the same constant number, all units will always do the same damage after calculation and always will move same at every replay, die and do same damage at every replay. All the hardest work will be on javascript - to make calculations using this constant number. 
My random number can be any. If first fight i generate random number "17", and next battle i generate random number "19666516546", it will not mean that battle with number "17" will do less damage - they all will do the "random" damage 0~15 to every unit, but replays with same formations, unit numbers, starting position and this random generated number will be always the same -> no more need to save any files! And i can add various spec effects, add something like defences, evasions, and all will fit in two MySQL rows - for every team :) Cool!!

Comment: can  you provide some of your code so we can see your loop and offer suggestions

Comment: Focus on local changes (Revision Control System), with snapshots (maybe)

Comment: if you just want to store these files as some kind of archive use some kind of compression like zip or gzip to make these files smaller. Should work very well with just ascii characters.

Comment: Your project looks insane! I'd really like to see what the result looks like!

Comment: Don't write out the full description of every unit every frame. Write them out once, then print only the deltas between frames, and even then only the minimal information needed to identify which unit changed and how. If you want to replay a game and seek quickly to different spots in the replay, you'll also want to put key frames every so often, exactly how video works.

Comment: Instead of having all units separately treat them as group with count of persons identified by health.  For example group 100 units as one with 1000 health points and every unit has 10 health, so with 500 health, you end up with 50 Units in this group. So you need to calculate only battles and movement for 4.000 instead of 40.000. Downside is, your units can not move separately but you could have a nice military formation instead. In combination with just saving changes (not whole array again but only delta movements) you save lots of data.

Comment: Should point out 25 fps is not even close to "real time".

Comment: This should be moved to the gamedev.stackexchange as there are more qualified people there who know how to optimize game mechanics. And its more on point there in my view.

Comment: Thx for that many responses! Sorry for late response :) I will decide which one solution is best tomorrow, need to think about every of them :) And also will try some out, to see the results :)

Comment: Look into Test Driven Design, for one thing, as it will help you manage the complexity more sanely.

Comment: @mansim Yes, certainly, you can seed the random number generator to get re-playable battles.  If you can get the browser to execute fast enough you won't have to pass anything except the random number -- saving a ton of money on storage and bandwidth use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` can be implicit in the storage medium.  Sure, that means you have to save gaps, but you can compress said gaps.

```
'x' => 1488, 
'y' => 1269,
```

depending on the canvas size, this can be compressed.  If the canvas is 1e6 x 1e6 (a million by a million), there are 1e12 locations, which fits in ~40 bits.

```
'team' => 'red',
```

with 2 sides, this is 1 bit.

```
'health' => 10,
```

the vast majority of units have a low health.  So what we can do is that units with a health < 15 are stored in 4 bits.  If all the bits are set, we have to look up the units health elsewhere (with an id->health table).

```
'target' => [1486, 1271]
```

We could store an independent target for each unit, but that probably doesn't match how the UI works.  You probably select a pile of units, and tell them to go somewhere, no?  ~40 bits for a location, ~24 bits for a reference count, for 8 bytes per target.

If we give each side a limit of ~65k targets, that is 16 bits.

16+4+1+40 = 61 bits.  Which means we have 3 more bits to play with to pack them into a 64 bit per unit.

At 64 bits per unit, that is 160k per side.  Plus up to half-a-meg of target data, but that can be handled dynamically.

Plus a health overflow table (that maps id to health), which should usually be close to empty.  If you do this sometimes, you can set up before-after id maps to maintain a consistent history (say, when half the units are dead, you do a compression pass with a before-after id mapping).

If id need not be consistent, you can compress the units down so that they are no longer sparse.

The target trick -- the target could be a unit ID if less than 40,000, and if above that value it would be a waypoint.  That reduces your waypoints to ~15k ones.  (I was assuming target was set by the UI, where someone would select a chunk of units, an order them to go somewhere).

You'd want to iterate over the packed data, skipping "dead" units (bitmask on health), unpacking them into a usable structure, evaluating their action, and writing them back.  Double-buffering is an option (where you read from one buffer, and write to another), but it has a modest cost.  Because units are fixed size, you can lookup other units fast (and unpack them), which helps if your targets are other unit ids, and with things like doing damage.

Single-buffering makes things easier, because things like simultaneous damage are tricky.  It does mean that lower-id units act first -- you can fix this by flipping a coin each turn to determine if you iterate forward or backwards (and stick one side in low-ids, the other in high-ids), or make that an initiative check at the start of combat.

Comment: My canvas is 1800x912 to fit on window. But this is not constant yet. I trough maybe to set them not as key=>value, but only as value, so your binary seems ok. And about target - i think i can calculate everything on background, so target probably wont need on foreground, maybe its not important for watcher who attacks who when so many units. Probably would need x/y, health, team. Yes, teams only 2 always. So, without targets, there should be 45 bits?

Comment: "At 64 bits per unit, that is 160k per side." it was for 2000 units probably. For 20k units thats 1600k per side. is that right?

Comment: @mansim 64 bits is 8 bytes.  8 * 20,000 = 160k.  The canvas can fit in 21 bits -- I'd do 11 bits vertical 10 bits horizontal (so 2048 x 1024 location).

Comment: your answer seems to be best here :) I did all the calculations you gave, it was best way.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the PHP side of things here is some initialization material to set up red and blue teams randomly. You'll notice that the data being stored is in the form of human readable strings so it is relatively easy to see what is going on just by looking at the data.

```
$red   = array();   // stats per red unit
$blue  = array();  // stats per blue unit
$sites = array();  // units (red and/or blue) at a location

$start = microtime(true);

echo "Generating red team:<br>\n";
for ($r=0; $r<20000; $r++)
{
  $x = mt_rand(0,1940/2);
  $y = mt_rand(0,1280);
  $h = 10;

  $red[$r] = "r:$r;x:$x;y:$y;h:$h";
  if ( $r < 3 )
    echo "... " . $red[$r] . "<br>\n";
  if ( $r == 3 )
    echo "...<br>\n";
  if ( $r >= 19997 )
    echo "... " . $red[$r] . "<br>\n";

  @$sites[$x][$y][] = "r:$r";
}
$now = microtime(true);
echo "Red side generated, total time used " . ($now - $start) . "<br><br>\n";

echo "Generating blue team:<br>\n";
for ($b=0; $b<20000; $b++)
{
  $x = mt_rand(1940/2,1940);
  $y = mt_rand(0,1280);
  $h = 10;

  $blue[$b] = "b:$b;x:$x;y:$y;h:$h\n";
  if ( $b < 3 )
    echo "... " . $blue[$b] . "<br>\n";
  if ( $b == 3 )
    echo "...<br>\n";
  if ( $b >= 19997 )
    echo "... " . $blue[$b] . "<br>\n";

  @$sites[$x][$y][] = "b:$b";
}
$now = microtime(true);
echo "Blue side generated, total time used " . ($now - $start) . "<br><br>\n";

$sum = 0;
foreach ($sites as $x => $list)
  $sum += count($list);
echo "$sum screen locations contain one or more units<br>\n";
```

The output from this shows that we can generate 40,000 units at random locations and then track all units by screen x,y location, or site, for later use within a very short period of time.

```
Generating red team:
... r:0;x:49;y:642;h:10
... r:1;x:508;y:1162;h:10
... r:2;x:444;y:8;h:10
...
... r:19997;x:553;y:851;h:10
... r:19998;x:608;y:414;h:10
... r:19999;x:860;y:1203;h:10
Red side generated, total time used 0.070003986358643

Generating blue team:
... b:0;x:1799;y:445;h:10 
... b:1;x:1913;y:177;h:10 
... b:2;x:1730;y:678;h:10 
...
... b:19997;x:1586;y:919;h:10 
... b:19998;x:1445;y:3;h:10 
... b:19999;x:1061;y:542;h:10 
Blue side generated, total time used 0.14700794219971

39697 screen locations contain one or more units
```

In terms of file storage, I would suggest something similar to that suggested by others. You would probably write the full initialization state to file and then list adjustments to that state on a frame by frame basis. Your PHP code would then adjust state to generate display effects by reading changes on a frame by frame basis.

Before I continue I wonder if you could reply with some information about what you mean by targeting. Is this movement destination with combat occurring automatically when nearby? Also, why do you look for and find nearby friend and enemy units? Is this to adjust combat effects or to generate movement actions?

The following function demonstrates locating nearby units. Notice that the blue and the red are randomly place on opposite sides of the screen by the above so you aren't likely to see any nearby foes.

```
function nearby($unit, $sites, $withinx=5, $withiny=5, $verbose=0)
{
  if ( $verbose )
    echo "Looking for units near unit '$unit'<br>\n";

  $data = explode(';',$unit);
  foreach ($data as $datum)
  {
    if ( strncmp($datum,"x:",2)==0 )
      $x = (integer)substr($datum,2);
    if ( strncmp($datum,"y:",2)==0 )
      $y = (integer)substr($datum,2);
  }

  if ( $verbose )
    echo "... this unit is located at ($x,$y)<br>\n";

  $nearby = array();
  for ($sx = $x - $withinx; $sx <= $x + $withinx; $sx++)
  {
    for ($sy = $y - $withiny; $sy <= $y + $withiny; $sy++)
    {
      $list = @$sites[$sx][$sy];
      if ( count($list) )
      {
        foreach ($list as $key => $candidate)
        {
          if ( strncmp($candidate,$unit,strlen($candidate))==0 )
            continue;

          $nearby[] = $candidate;
          if ( $verbose )
            echo "... ... unit at $sx,$sy found: $candidate<br>\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $nearby;
}
```

Then, some code to run several thousand closeness checks with verbose mode turned on for the first few.

```
echo "<br>\n";
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
  $r = mt_rand(0,19999);

  $verbose = 0;
  if ( $i < 2 )
    $verbose = 1;

  nearby($red[$r],$sites,5,5,$verbose);
}
echo "1000 red units randomly checked for nearby units<br>\n";

echo "<br>\n";
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
  $r = mt_rand(0,19999);

  $verbose = 0;
  if ( $i < 2 )
    $verbose = 1;

  nearby($blue[$r],$sites,5,5,$verbose);
}
echo "1000 blue units randomly checked for nearby units<br>\n";

$now = microtime(true);
echo "<br>Total time used " . ( $now - $start) . "<br>\n";
```

Sample output from the search for nearby units follows:

```
Looking for units near unit 'r:16452;x:332;y:944;h:10'
... this unit is located at (332,944)
... ... unit at 335,945 found: r:3376
... ... unit at 336,948 found: r:14128
Looking for units near unit 'r:4414;x:3;y:1223;h:10'
... this unit is located at (3,1223)
... ... unit at 2,1219 found: r:1210
... ... unit at 8,1226 found: r:461
1000 red units randomly checked for nearby units

Looking for units near unit 'b:4002;x:1531;y:224;h:10 '
... this unit is located at (1531,224)
... ... unit at 1530,222 found: b:11267
Looking for units near unit 'b:3006;x:1011;y:349;h:10 '
... this unit is located at (1011,349)
1000 blue units randomly checked for nearby units

Total time used 0.56303095817566 (including generation, above)
```

### Best Way to Save Files on Server

No matter how you do this you'll end up accumulating serious data if you want to store large numbers of games. The data you save can be reduced to initial state details followed by updates to that state data. You could end up with something similar to the following:

[Frame 0]
Game State
[Frame 1]
State Changes

...

[Frame X]
Last State
[Post Game]
Wrap up details (scores, etc)

For longer term storage you can compress the game state data and zap it up to Amazon's S3 storage system (or something similar). Playback will only involve generating frames quick enough based on the stream of state changes.

If you do store rendering information you might find that certain region, or strips, of the game board end up empty and unchanging for long periods of time. This too can reduce the data flowing between your unit state engine and your rendering engine.

### Fastest Way to Calculate Battle

The language you use to generate or calculate the battle does not have to be the same language as your rendering engine. For example, you could have your rendering engine requesting frames from a separate state management engine. As long as the interfaces stay the same you could upgrade battle calculation, state replay and frame data generation systems as needed.

If time and interest permit I'd go with PHP at first just to get the kinks out of the system -- then invest in whatever portion gives you the biggest bang next. However, I like the challenge of pushing PHP and trying to get "fast" from a language some people assume is slow.

Don't hesitate to store additional state details (that are not written out) during the game. For example, above, I've stored the list of units keyed by the X,Y location on the screen. This attempts to provide a quick path for determining which other units are close to a unit. Anything that takes a long time to iterate through might be better served by a maintained data set that can be looked up via key.

As for the calculation itself, I'm going to suggest that you consider ways to reduce the amount of effort that is happening. Though you have 40,000 units on screen you don't have to process every one of them every frame. You could instead, for example, process all of them per 10 frames while adjusting the scope of action per unit processed to keep the pace of the game the same.

If needed, you can provide rules and reasons for behavior that reduces your processing load. For example, if a unit moved last frame it is not ready to fight until the +Nth frame. If a unit was wounded it must wait until the +Nth frame, healing 1 in the process, before continuing. To adjust for these processing friendly delays you could increase movement rates and damage rates.

Again, don't confuse the size of the battle processing state system with the amount of information that must be saved to replay the game. The state system can load up on data used to make processing more efficient without saving that data anywhere as long as it can be regenerated during playback.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the size, you're probably best off *not* using JSON. From the structure you gave, it seems that each of the elements can fit in two bytes, meaning that each unit datum will only take up around 12 bytes or so. Since you're saving to disk, the cost of serialization and deserialization is not important compared to the cost of disk I/O.

I'd recommend using a binary format for this:

```
2 bytes for id
2 bytes for x
2 bytes for y
1 byte for color
1 byte for health
4 bytes for target
```

which is 12 bytes long. To do this is slightly clunky in Javascript, but can be done by using the bitwise operators to pull bytes out of a string, for instance:

```
var ustr = <get unit string somehow>
var unit = {};
unit.id = ustr.charCodeAt(0);
unit.x  = ustr.charCodeAt(1);
unit.y  = ustr.charCodeAt(2);
var teamAndHealth = ustr.charCodeAt(3);
unit.team = teams[teamAndHealth >>> 8];
unit.health = teamAndHealth & 0xFF;
unit.target = [ustr.charCodeAt(4), ustr.charCodeAt(5)];
```

As for *generating* the data, PHP is probably not your best choice either. I'd recommend using a language such as C#, Perl, or Java, which can all write binary data quite easily, and have automatic garbage collection to make your life easier.

Comment: Only 16 more convenient to use for references to the file

Comment: Good point, the OP might also need to use the extra space later.

Comment: So, to compile that with C++ should be the fastest way? And i decided that target maybe isn't important on foreground. And i trough again, maybe instead of 40frames/s should not be so uncomfortable to use 100frames/s and i should save more.